# Unable to redirect to a page after session timeout in Laravel 9

Tags: laravel

I have implemented session timeout in a Laravel 9 application through the CheckSessionTimeout class in middleware.

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;

class CheckSessionTimeout
{
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
    if (Auth::check() && !$request->session()->has('lastActivityTime')) {
        $request->session()->put('lastActivityTime', time());
    }

    $maxIdleTime = config('session.lifetime') * 60;


    if (Auth::check() && $request->session()->has('lastActivityTime') && 
            (time() - $request->session()->get('lastActivityTime') > $maxIdleTime)) 
    {
        dd('session timing out...');
        // set a session variable 'sessionTimedOut' to true 
        $request->session()->put('sessionTimedOut', true);
        //  Auth::logout();
      
        //  return redirect('/logout');
    }
   // dd('in CheckSessionTimeout');
    $request->session()->put('lastActivityTime', time());

    return $next($request);
}
}
```

The laravel application seems to be using this class as if I uncomment `// dd('in CheckSessionTimeout');`, the application displays this message as soon as I try to login. After the session times out, the application is logging out the user and redisplays the login in page.

My issues is that it does not seems to be coming to the **timed out** if section (It never executes `dd('session timing out...');`, thus not allowing me to control the page to display after the user is logged out.

Any help is greatly appreicaited.

Comment: the session uses a recaller, if they are using the 'remember me' functionality then it will automatically log them back in but the other session vars will not be there ... so they will be logged in the but that lastactive won't exist

Comment: @lagbox I am not using “Remember me”. My main confusion is that why it is not going in “session timed out” of “if”, as I want the user to take to the the session timeout page, and not the login page (as it happening now)